# Why isn't the C# compiler able to cast a literal negative value to an enum?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, casting, roslyn

This code does not compile with the [latest C# compiler](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/f:>il/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayAkhGQBRCMHQB+GFRgBeGGIXLV6CQFoAjDlkBfbLbyES5VMZiGVamAC4YkZM2sgA===):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IntEnum a = (IntEnum)-1;
    }
}

public enum IntEnum : int { }
```

When you attempt to compile it, it raises

> (3,22,3,29): Error CS0119: 'IntEnum' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Strangely, changing the casted value to a positive number (such as `4`), or using a const value (such as `int.MinValue`), or even surrounding the value with parentheses like `(IntEnum)(-1)` will compile and work just fine. However, the above sample does not.

Is there any reason for this? Is it possible that Roslyn is perhaps parsing the code incorrectly, and that's why an error is getting raised?

Comment: @Alexei: thanks. So "by design", because `IntEnum` is a user-defined identifier, not a predefined type. (Keeping in mind that's the old spec and apparently an old error code...but same thing probably applies in C# 6 too). It seems this is not new for C# 6 either.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've converted comment to answer as it is documented in totally different error.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: yes I see. Note that the "totally different error" is not emitted by the C# 6 compiler, which IMHO is a bug. An error message doesn't get much better than "To cast a negative value, you must enclose the value in parentheses". It's a shame that message isn't shown by the new compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Behavior is expected and documented to allow expressions like `(Var)-1` to be parsed.

[Compiler Error CS0075](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfd1ef4y.aspx) goes into spec details (I would expect you to get that error instead/in addition to CS0119):

> To cast a negative value, you must enclose the value in parentheses
>   If you are casting using a keyword that identifies a predefined type, then you do not need parentheses. Otherwise, you must put the parentheses because (x) –y will not be considered a cast expression. From the C# Specification, Section 7.6.6:
>
> *From the disambiguation rule it follows that, if x and y are identifiers, (x)y, (x)(y), and (x)(-y) are cast-expressions, but (x)-y is not, **even if x identifies a type**. However, if x is a keyword that identifies a predefined type (such as int), then all four forms are cast-expressions (because such a keyword could not possibly be an expression by itself).*

Comment: Noting that this is not new to the C# 6 compiler, I do see that one significant difference is that in C# 5, the errors include CS0075, which unambiguously explains the issue, while that error or an equivalent is _not_ shown in C# 6. IMHO, that part is actually a bug, as it's a regression from the old compiler.